# confusion about sequence length in dynamic rnn version of tensor flow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

i am training a RNN to classify a sequence of input (13 values at each time step) as a particular class.
Here is relevant part of my code (line numbers prefixed)

```
 50 data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 40,13]) #Number of examples, number of input, dimension of each input
 51 target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
 52 num_hidden = 24
 53 cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_hidden,state_is_tuple=True)
 54 val, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, data, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Here my I have padded (prefixed and value zero) to each input sequence of a batch to make it 40x13.(padding operation not shown in above code)
So RNN will consider the past 40 steps for each example and then one hot vector of target will tell it to which class the example belongs.
Also, I made sure that output class of each example is 1 or2 (never zero).

I saw https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn which mentions sequence_length parameter.

Que 1) Can it be used for each example in a batch or across a batch ?
Que 2) Also, can you suggest me way to vary this value for each batch or across batch (whichever is relevant) assuming that I have a integer array seq_len which stores the desired value for each batch or each example (whichever is relevant) ?

[quote]sequence_length: (optional) An int32/int64 vector sized [batch_size]. Used to copy-through state and zero-out outputs when past a batch element's sequence length. So it's more for correctness than performance.[/quote]

Que 3) Suppose I set it to 14 - does that mean RNN will consider first 14 timestep and carry the output state(call it O<sub>14</sub>) after 14th step and ignore the input at 15th to 40th step (consider it all zeroes) and then associate O<sub>14</sub> with the target vector. So then I won't have to prefixed zero padding ?

Thanks.
Do you need more code to understand this situation ?

PS: My setup

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'1.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

1) `sequence_length` a vector `Tensor` with length equal to your batch size (so "yes")

2) It is assuming your padding is suffixed rather than prefixed (but otherwise sounds like exactly what you want).

For an example I'd check the [unit tests](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/714f3c4f2f901e865bfcbf830485adafb92dca48/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/rnn_test.py#L530).

Comment: thanks for replying.
You mean , I would have to suffix pad my short examples in batch
Also the output state will be carried over to the end.
The advantage is that this will save computation.
is that right ?

Comment: Yes, state will propagate. I don't think it's any faster than running the RNN over a rectangular block of data (possibly slightly slower). It just helps you avoid training your RNN on large blocks of zeros (as the documentation says, it's for correctness rather than speed).

Comment: ok . 
I will post a complete code after getting it running using variable sequence_length. 
WIll need a few days then I will update this page.
Will let you know if I get stuck again (last I tried, i gave up. Will start fresh again).
Thanks.